# Mini jQuery script makes div disappear instead of replacing its content

Tags: jquery, html, toggle

I'm just getting started with Javascript and jQuery so don't get mad if this is a really dumb question. We're supposed to replace the contents of a `div` by binding a `toggle` function but when I run it, the entire `div` "shrinks" away. What am I doing wrong? The mini script is

```
function highlight(evt){
    $('#evtTarget').toggleClass('highlighted');
}

function func_1(evt){
    $('#evtTarget').html("CLICK!!");
}

function func_2(evt){
    $('#evtTarget').html("CLACK!!");
}

$(function(){
    $('#evtTarget').hover(highlight,highlight);
    $('#evtTarget').toggle(func_1,func_2);
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NZjvJ/2

Comment: `toggle`, the way you are trying to use it, was deprecated in 1.8 and removed in 1.9.  Here is a fiddle using 1.7, which works. http://jsfiddle.net/hhwmW/.  See the big note on this page: http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Comment: I see, the course is based on jQuery 1.3 and that caused trouble before with missing quotes in attribute filters.

Comment: According to the course, `toggle` should toggle between two functions operating on an HTML object (the `div` for this case). So that's no longer the case and that's why it's working for the instructor but not for me...

Comment: jQuery 1.3? That's over four years old :/

Answer (score 1):

[`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) shows or hides the element, it doesn't switch between two arbitrary states (**Update:** as @sberry pointed out in the coments, it used to behave the way you intended to in versions up to 1.8).

When you call it using a `function` argument (which, as the docs show, is not a valid argument for either of its use cases), it behaves just as if it were called with no arguments (i.e. show if it's hidden, hide if it's shown). Since the divs were visible at the start, they get hidden.

Answer (score 1):

see this for toggle documentation:

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

if you wish to replace content on hover ..you should replace your lines with below code;

```
function onhover(evt){
 $('#evtTarget').toggleClass('highlighted');
$('#evtTarget').html("hover in!!");
}


function onhoverout(evt){
 $('#evtTarget').toggleClass('highlighted');
$('#evtTarget').html("hover out!!");
}

$(function(){
    $('#evtTarget').hover(onhover,onhoverout);
//below toggle is not suggested to use like this.
    $('#evtTarget').toggle(func_1,func_2);
});
```

'
hope it helps.correct if im wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fixed version: http://jsfiddle.net/NZjvJ/3/

`.toggle()` shows/hides an element. I don't think that's what you wanted.

```
function highlight(evt){
    $('#evtTarget').toggleClass('highlighted');
}

function func_1(evt){
    if( $('#evtTarget').html() !== 'CLICK!!' ) $('#evtTarget').html("CLICK!!");
    else $('#evtTarget').html("CLACK!!");
}

$(function(){
    $('#evtTarget').hover(highlight,highlight);
    $('#evtTarget').click(func_1);
});
```

Comment: is wasn't familiar with jsFiddle yet, but it seems to come in really handy. Thx for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

the `toggle()` function you wish to use was deprecated as described here http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

The function now has been replaced by a function that toggles between `show()` and `hide()`. http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

What you want is something like this:

```
function highlight(evt){
    $('#evtTarget').toggleClass('highlighted');
}
function func_1(evt){
    $('#evtTarget').html("CLICK!!");
    $('#evtTarget').unbind('click',func_1);
    $('#evtTarget').click(func_2);
}

function func_2(evt){
    $('#evtTarget').html("CLACK!!");
    $('#evtTarget').unbind('click',func_2);
    $('#evtTarget').click(func_1);
}
$('#evtTarget').hover(highlight,highlight);
$('#evtTarget').click(func_1);
```

Comment: I find that a bit confusing... You call `func_1` within the definition of `func_1`? Isn't that a bit like a circular reference?

Comment: @RubenGeert my code works in place of your example. What I am doing is replicating the toggle function by unbinding itself as an event, and rebinding the other function.

Comment: I see, you're right and it works. It just looks a bit strange to me.

Answer (score 0):

what are you trying to do is use toggle in document.ready.... toggle.. shows the divs if hidden else hides it... so now i bet your evtTarget is visible on document.ready and hence the toggle function hides it...(with no other events calling toggle to show the hidden div again)

what you need is an event for toggle like click ,or  hover or keup any event ....

```
$(function(){
   $('#someDiv').click(function(){
      $('#evtTarget').toggle(func_1,func_2);
   });
});
```

Comment: @bipen not the downvoter, but I believe your answer is indeed incorrect. The OP wanted a behavior that was deprecated (that of a "toggle button", or a "checkbox"), not the show/hide one. Calling the current `toggle` on `click` callback won't accomplish that, and the old one would work just fine in `document.ready`.

Comment: @mgibsonbr No, the OP (me) wanted to figure out what he misunderstood. The main problem seems to be that my course uses jQuery 1.3 and I'm on jQuery 1.9.